# IE7 Floated list Items formatting issues

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-7

Towards the bottom there are link list items. For some reason in IE7 the formatting looks off. I'm not entirely sure why that is and what I need to do to fix it.

http://sandbox.solutionsbydesign.com/hughes/?page_id=43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your ul with id="options" add the css property:  whitespace: nowrap;

This will make sure that your list items don't wrap to a second line within their LI area instead forcing the LI to wrap to the second and third lines.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Why does IE do that and what other situation is it good to use whitespace? I've never really used that CSS property before.

Comment: Well what that property does is it doesn't allow spaces to cause line breaks.  I believe in other browsers it treats spaces that are not inside of a paragraph element as "non-breaking spaces" so this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Post your CSS/HTML code snippets. Try display: inline-block in sub-menu li class